# how to loop through asp.net control dynamically?

Tags: c#, placeholder

I created 4 place holder in aspx page. I named them placeHolder1, placeHolder2, placeHolder3, placeHolder4. How do I add content to these place holder dynamically in the loop? I know I could replicate four different times, but I want to save some code and do it in the loop. Is it actually possible to do so?

Comment: Can you show some of the code involved, e.g. the aspx code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
{
 PlaceHolder myControl = FindControl("placeHolder" + i) as PlaceHolder;
 //Do whatever with control;
}
```

Comment: it's not finding control it gives me null exception!

Answer (score 3):

You can loop through all controls on the page, and find the **Type** you're interested in like this:

```
foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
{
    if (ctrl is ContentPlaceHolder)
    {
        ContentPlaceHolder cph = (ContentPlaceHolder)ctrl;

        if (cph.ID == "placeHolder1")
        {
            // do whatever
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this code, but it serves to give the general idea of how you'd iterate through your place holders.

Comment: He does not want to add an if line for each individual placeHolder

Comment: @jbkkd Maybe, this solution is a more general approach that demonstrates how to iterate through controls of a Type, where the ID is an afterthought. Your solution is best when you're interested in locating a control (or controls) specifically by its ID.

Comment: Indeed your right, and that's what HardCode asked - how to iterate on his four controls with their ID.